# Excel user defined function : matching a string using regex by cycling through several values passed into the function as a range

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have several rows of data which I need to match with data in another sheet, then input the values found in the matched columns back into the same sheet. The problem is set up like this:

I have some input data as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: input_sheet]

For each entry in the "name" field (column B), I want to reach into another sheet, I'll call it the "reference sheet", which is structured as shown below:

[image: regex_column]

..then cycle through the entries in column E and wherever there is a match, pick the values in column A, B and the row number of the match, and plug them back in to the input sheet as additional columns at the end. The result will look like this:

[image: result]

Note that the input data "name" fields contain entries that are not 'clean', but still contain the string that will be present in one of the rows of the 'reference sheet'. In this example, row 3 contains the entry "Rostock A"which matches E6 and E8 in the "reference sheet". Due to this reason, I thought of using `regex` and wrote a VBA Function which, for the moment, is not doing what I expect it to do:

```
Public Function test_regex_func(input_cell As Range, _
                            regex_range As Range _
                            ) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Dim regexpr As Object
    Set regexpr = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    Dim arrOutputValues() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    For Each regex_entry In regex_range
        regexpr.Pattern = regex_entry

        If regexpr.test(input_cell.Value) Then
        ' get the row number of the match
        arrOutputValues(i) = regex_entry.Row
        i = i + 1 'increment array index only if there is a match

        End If
    Next regex_entry

test_regex_func = arrOutputValues

ErrHandl:
    test_regex_func = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Right now, I'm only trying to return the row number(s) of the matched rows of the "reference sheet", but I'm only getting back a `#VALUE!` error. So my questions are:

- Where am I going wrong here?
- How can I extend this function to return also the values in columns A and B?

The test data is available for download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02OIFrBsi3oMEE2UVltNkVyWGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you really need VBA for this? A simple formula will do but it will use array processing and might not be suitable for >1000 rows. For that matter, what is the highest frequency (aka number of instances) for any one particular name?

Comment: I thought of that, but I am not too fluent with Excel functions beyond basic lookups and index-match, so I tend to look toward VBA although clearly I'm stuck there too at the moment ;)..the highest frequency will not be more than 10, but I'm pretty sure it is closer to 4 - 5.

Comment: Still need to know what kind of scope you are talking about; whether it is worthwhile to use variant arrays or if worksheet processing is fast enough. How many rows are there in the flat table?

Comment: 1300 rows in the flat sheet, and ~5000 in the "reference sheet".

Comment: I started getting into this and I keep coming back to one question. Why not take this opportunity to **repair** the data so that there is a direct one-to-many relationship without wildcards or regex? "ROSTOCK A" can be identified as the tail end of "MAINPLANTRostockA" once case sensitivity is discarded and interim spaces are removed. Can you provide examples of some of the more finicky comparisons that might produce false positives (as sample data in a code box, not an image)? Which would you like to keep? Is there a "ROSTOCK AA"?

Comment: You are right, I'm looking into having the data repaired, but it is coming from some external database so it may take time or not at all. In fact, I thought of writing regex for that very reasons, and my goal was to whittle down as many matches as I could with it. The problem is that there are several "fuzzy" matches. I've added some more examples in an updated Excel file that I have provided a link to at the end of my question. Is that ok for you to work with?

Comment: I'll definitely have a look.